# Are there any examples of hyperbolic curves over finite fields such that the action of frobenius on its prime-to-$p$ fundamental group is known?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, fundamental-group

Let $X$ smooth curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of type $(g,n)$ - that is, $X$ is an open subscheme of its genus $g$ compactification obtained by removing $n$ points.

Any such curve determines an exact sequence of etale fundamental groups

$$1\rightarrow \pi_1(X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q})\rightarrow \pi_1(X)\rightarrow\underbrace{\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q/\mathbb{F}_q)}_{G_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q}}\rightarrow 1$$
whence a representation
$$\rho' : G_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q}\rightarrow\text{Out}(\pi_1(X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q}))\rightarrow \text{Out}(\pi_1'(X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q}))$$
where $\pi'$ denotes the prime-to-$p$ fundamental group. (Actually since the absolute galois group of a finite field is projective, the exact sequence is split, and so we get an actual representation into $\text{Aut}(\cdots)$)

Are there any examples where $X$ is hyperbolic (equivalently, $\pi_1'(X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q})$ is nonabelian) such that the representation $\rho'$ is known?

This is equivalent to understanding the action of Frobenius on $\pi_1'(X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q})$.

References would also be appreciated.

Comment: your exact sequence splits, so your outer action lifts to a real one.

Comment: @Niels Why does it split? Does every curve over a finite field have a rational point?

Comment: @oxeimon The absolute Galois group of a finite field is projective (actually free) profinite group, hence any epimorphism on it splits in the profinite category. It is not equivalent to existence of a rational  point

Comment: @LiorBary-Soroker Good point! Neat!

Comment: @oxeimon Sorry to barge in but: what is the definition of "hyperbolic curve"? Google failed to point at a decisive reference for this.

Comment: @SaalHardali No problem! A hyperbolic curve over a finite field is a smooth separated geometrically connected scheme of dimension 1 over a finite field such that if $g$ denotes the genus of its smooth compactification, and $n$ denotes the number of points one needs to add to compactify it, then either $g \ge 2$, $n\ge 3$, or $g = n = 1$.

Comment: @SaalHardali The terminology comes from the following: Given a finite type Riemann surface $X$ of type $(g,n)$ (that is, it is obtained by removing $n$ points from a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$), then there are 3 possibilities for the universal cover of $X$. Either the universal cover is $\mathbb{C}$ (the geometry is flat), or $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ (the geometry is spherical), or it is the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ (the geometry is hyperbolic).

Comment: @SaalHardali The hyperbolic case is the 'most frequent'. $X$ is flat if $(g,n) \in \{(1,0),(0,1),(0,2)\}$, and spherical if $(g,n) = (0,0)$, and hyperbolic otherwise.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Do you know a standard basic reference for this topic? in particular one that proves that statement of yours about hyperbolic and non-abelian etale fundamental group.

Comment: @SaalHardali Sorry I realized that in my characterization of "hyperbolic" as equivalent to its $\pi_1$ being nonabelian, I should have said that it is equivalent to $\pi_1'$ being nonabelian (fixed now). At this point, it follows from the standard fact that the prime-to-$p$ fundamental group is isomorphic to the prime-to-$p$ completion of a smooth lift to characteristic 0 (this comes from the grothendieck theory of specialization for $\pi_1$.s) For this, see for example SGA 1 Expose XIII, Cor 2.12

Comment: I am really uneducated in most of the terminology you’re using (that’s not in any way your problem, though) but I am also studying hyperbolic curves over finite fields and I was just wondering: have you tried computing results for a curve over a smaller finite field? Would that even tell you anything useful? I’m mainly a software person so my first instinct is to use that to get a feel for concrete examples. I’m going to add your question here to my list of things to explore.

Comment: @tuespetre I think one fundamental difficulty in answering the question (ie, "knowing the action of frobenius") is that it would amount to specifying an automorphism of a free profinite group (or something close to it), and such automorphisms seem very difficult to write down. For example, you could try writing down the images of two generators, but how would one even write down in a readable way an "arbitrary" element of a free profinite group?